# Wordpress jQuery click event

Tags: jquery, wordpress, syntax

I have this code here that should send off an alert...

```
jQuery(".wpcart_gallery .thickbox").click(function($){
            alert('hi');
        });
```

But it doesnt work :( there are no errors and the alert never appears. I have the correct JQuery.js file in my header...is there something wrong with my syntax?

Here is the HTML code

```
<div class="wpcart_gallery" style="text-align:center; padding-top:5px;">
<a class="thickbox cboxElement" href="DSC_0037.jpg" rev="DSC_0037.jpg"></a>
<a class="thickbox cboxElement" href="DSC_0036.jpg"  rev="DSC_0036.jpg"></a>
<a class="thickbox cboxElement" href="DSC_0118.jpg" rev="DSC_0118.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

I am trying to have a click event when one of the links inside wpcart_gallery is clicked.

Here is the page, blow the big image there are three images, I am looking for click event to trigger if any of those images are clicked...http://www.taranmarlowjewelry.com/?wpsc-product=product-1-2

Comment: Is that JavaScript within a `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` call? Can you provide the site or a jsFiddle in which this is observable?

Comment: Yes it is inside a `jQuery('document').ready(function($){....});`

Comment: `'document'` and `document` are different. Remove the `'`s and try it.

Comment: that wont work at all inside wordpress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the issue by

```
jQuery(".wpcart_gallery img").click(function($){
            alert('hi');
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Could be that you have invalid HTML.  None of the following have closing tags:

```
<a class="thickbox cboxElement" href="DSC_0037.jpg" rev="DSC_0037.jpg">
<a class="thickbox cboxElement" href="DSC_0036.jpg"  rev="DSC_0036.jpg">
<a class="thickbox cboxElement" href="DSC_0118.jpg" rev="DSC_0118.jpg">
```

If I were jQuery I'd be confused.

If I add closing tags it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/GtgEy/

Comment: Yes they have those, just forgot to put them in

Answer (score 0):

Likely you need to use delegated bindings:

```
jQuery(window).on('click', ".wpcart_gallery .thickbox", function(ev){
    alert('hi');

    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

You can replace `window` with some other parent element if you can. Given:

```
<div id="test">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
</div>
```

you could do:

```
jQuery("#test").on('click', 'a', function(ev) {
    alert('hi');

    ev.preventDefault();
});
```